# Node.js + Mustache to Preprocess Static HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, mustache

I'm working on a project that requires static HTML pages to be converted into new static HTML pages.  I scraped the pages with Cheerio for content and stored the relationships between pages as JSON.

The challenge is to produce a static html page with a Table of Contents that interconnects everything.

Mustache Template:

```
<h1>Table of Contents</h1>
{{#toc}}
    <h2>{{moduleName}}</h2>
    <ul class='module'>
        {{#page}}
            <li><a href='{{url}}'>{{title}}</a></li>
        {{/page}}
    </ul>
{{/toc}}
```

Data:

```
{
    "toc": [{
        "moduleName": "Getting Started",
        "page": [{
            "title": "Welcome",
            "url": "L0-01_Welcome.html"
        }, {
            "title": "Who Should Read This?",
            "url": "L0-02_WhoFor.html"
        }]
    }, {
        "moduleName": "Module 1",
        "page": [{
            "title": "Definitions",
            "url": "L1-01_Definitions.html"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Node Setup:

```js
var Mustache = require("mustache");
var fs = require("fs");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");

// File Paths
var pathToMustache = "./templates/toc.mustache";
var pathToJSON = "./menu/data.json";

// Generate HTML menu
//var htmlMenu = Mustache.render(fs.readFileSync(pathToMustache).toString(), fs.readFileSync(pathToJSON));
var htmlMenu = Mustache.to_html(fs.readFileSync(pathToMustache).toString(), fs.readFileSync(pathToJSON));
console.log(htmlMenu);

// Then loop through the html files appending the new menu using Cheerio...
```

This DOES successfully append `<h1>Table of Contents</h1>`, but nothing else.  I must be missing something very obvious, because I can't make sense of this.

I'm very new to mustache as well as programming in general, so advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You read JSON from a file as a text string and need to convert it to an object before invoking Mustache.render.

Use `JSON.parse`:

```
'use strict';

var Mustache = require("mustache");
var fs = require("fs");

var page = fs.readFileSync("page.mustache").toString();
var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("data.json").toString());

var h = Mustache.render(page, data);

console.log(h);
```

Output:

```
<h1>Table of Contents</h1>
    <h2>Getting Started</h2>
    <ul class='module'>
          <li><a href='L0-01_Welcome.html'>Welcome</a></li>
          <li><a href='L0-02_WhoFor.html'>Who Should Read This?</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Module 1</h2>
    <ul class='module'>
          <li><a href='L1-01_Definitions.html'>Definitions</a></li>
    </ul>
```

In JavaScript, there are basically two functions: [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

`JSON.parse` -- returns an object to the given JSON-text

`JSON.stringify` -- converts a value to JSON-notation.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That did the trick!!

So if I'm not mistaken, the JSON data exists in 3 different states:
1) ???
2) String
3) Object

Comment: JSON is a data exchange format. Basically, there are two functions: `JSON.parse` that returns an object to the given JSON-text and `JSON.stringify` that converts a value to JSON-notation.

Comment: Perhaps this is a breakdown in my overall understanding of the Node fs module.  My question was centered on the fact that the data exist in some form as `fs.readFile("data.json")` before it becomes a String.

Comment: To load it as an object, use: `var data = require('data.json')`, [here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) is the description.  LOAD_AS_FILE(X) : `3. If X.json is a file, parse X.json to a JavaScript Object.  STOP`